# How to invoke a jenkins pipeline A in another jenkins pipeline B to resolve

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a two jenkins file due the bulild purpose I was rename the file name ing.

How can I call to the in side the jenkins stage to call the another jenkins file.

plese help me to how to resolve this.

I have installed the jenkins plugin:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('one'){
            steps{
                echo 'hi'
            }
        }
        stage('two'){
            steps{
               
             build(job: 'ing')
            }
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

[git repo folder and file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiQ0O.png)

Answer (score 0):

To call downstream pipeline in another pipeline you have to call the pipeline by Jenkins job name:

```
...
    stages {
        stage('upstream job') {
            steps {
                build job: 'ing', parameters:
                        [
                            ...

                        ]
            }
        }
```

Job named `ing` has to be configured in Jenkins for this to work.